# SVN: Colleague checked in a folder into repository, but I can't Update my version to it

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

In showing a colleague how to use SVN yesterday, we created a test folder and file within our existing Visual Studio Solution. We'll call it "Test" folder with two files, "Test.ascx" and "Test.ascx.cs". We added it (or Visual SVN added it, 'cos it's awesome), and committed it. We also added and committed other files elsewhere in the project.

We can see it in the repository (and the other files).

Doing an update on my own machine to pull down these new files resulted in the other files being pulled down correctly, BUT the Test folder does not appear. No matter how many times I try Updating from various points in VS and in TortoiseSVN (urgh) Repo browser, it can't see that there are any changes to pull down.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a [known problem.](http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsMessageId=1881609&dsForumId=462)

You can use

$ svn update --depth=infinity

to force the update. With TortoiseSVN, use the "Update to revision" command in the Submenu, then change the depth combobox to "fully recursive".

Comment: Thank you! Proves it wasn't just me after all. ;)

Shame someone thought it worth losing a point to downgrade what seemed to be a valid question.

Comment: Thank you! I've been struggling with this one for the better part of the year. The conversations you linked to was great reading material.

Answer (score 3):

I've had ghost errors like this before and found the easiest work around is to delete the parent folder and update it's parent:

```
Project Root
    Project
        NewFolder
```

Delete *Project*, then Update *Project Root*

Answer (score 0):

> > We can see it in the repository (and the other files).
> >
> > ...
> >
> > No matter how many times I try Updating from various points in VS and in TortoiseSVN (urgh) Repo browser, it can't see that there are any changes to pull down.

So you **can** or **cannot** see it in the repository browser?

Comment: We *can* see both the Test folder and contents and the other files in the repository.

Comment: What happens if you create a new working copy (using Tortoise) and get the latest code from the repository? Do you then see those files? If you don't, then I guess they were committed to a different branch than your working copy is using.

Comment: Just tried that, and get 
"'C:\dev2008\MIGTurbo2\MIGTurbo2_WEB\secure' is already a working copy for a different URL"
We only have a single trunk copy at this time.

Comment: You need to do it on a **clean, empty, new** directory, not the existing one. It definitively mustn't contain any previous .svn directories inside.

Comment: Agreed I tried this later, using a hack I have to kill .svn folders. So, copied folder out, deleted .svn folders, and tried again ... just get conflicts.

Comment: Sorry, but it looks like you're not listening... I suggested creating a new separate working copy by using a fresh Windows directory... No "killing" of any .svns or anything... I think you should take a time and read http://svnbook.red-bean.com/ before even trying to get help on SO. People here are trying to help but they cannot if you do not understand the basics of SVN... And when you say you "hate" TortoiseSVN, it shows a lack of experience with SVN

Answer (score 0):

Did you commit and update the parent folder of your Test folder?

Comment: We committed the entire solution, which includes the "other files" and the Test folder, which is several folders deep.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, svn is always telling me to clean, did you try that?

Comment: Actually I just tried that. TortoiseSVN crashes. Did I mention I despise TortoiseSVN with all the passion of the damned?

Comment: You need to make sure that the SVN version Tortoise uses is compatible with the one from VisualSVN. And I recommend using the latest Tortoise... I haven't had any problems with Tortoise in 2 or so year's I've been using it.

Comment: I've updated to TortoiseSVN 1.6.1 and VisualSVN 1.7.1, still no change.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer, I know, but I have tried all the solutions you guys have kindly suggested and I just end up with conflicts, crashed TortoiseSVN and built up Karma. Therefore, a trusty edit in the .svn/entries file sorted it.

I have until now been a single developer using SVN just to manage my source code. Other people don't have problems, and I just check in stuff. I use Visual SVN as a layer to frig SVN for .NET (which it isn't great with) and I seem to constantly run into issues. I am performing very simple operations, not even branching/tagging. Simple simple simple. And yet I have issues with it?