# Adding images to SubVersion through Visual Studio using AnkhSVN - issues?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, svn, image, ankhsvn

For the most part, AnkhSVN is working well with VS2008.  The only issue I'm seeing is when an image is added from one dev, it is not added to any other machines when the SubVersion Update to Latest Version is executed.

The log file shows that the image was in fact added and submitted to SVN, but no file is downloaded added locally.

So far I've only seen this with .gif files.

Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the actual SVN server to make sure the file was added?  

Did they Add and check in or just Add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here for why this is and how to resolve it:
[SVN: Colleague checked in a folder into repository, but I can't Update my version to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805816/svn-colleague-checked-in-a-folder-into-repository-but-i-cant-update-my-version)

Answer (score 1):

Subversion is not natively supported by Visual Studio 2008. Which add-on are you using to access Subversion?

I would use the SVN command line client or TortoiseSVN to do a checkout of the source code and see whether it is committed properly. Then take a look at whether the project files have a reference to the file at all.

Comment: I even used TortoiseSVN to try to retrieve the file from the repository - same thing.  

As for the VS plug-in - Ankh.

Comment: I added references to AnhkSVN to the question subject and body, as well as to the tags.  This might help draw people who know more about AnkhSVN to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose you've added .gif files to your excluded list, right?  It's tough to do that unintentionally.  Worth at least looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also commit the project file. Most project files keep a list of items that should be included in the project. Adding a new file also adds it to that list.